# elastic search filter by documents count in nested document

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have this schema in elastic search.

```
79[
    'ID' : '1233',
    Geomtries:[{
        'doc1' : 'F1',
        'doc2' : 'F2'

    },
    (optional for some of the documents)
    {
        'doc2' : 'F1',
        'doc3' : 'F2'
    }]
]
```

the Geometries is a nested element. 
I want to get all of the documents that have one object inside Geometries.

Tried so far :

```
"script" : {"script" : "if (Geomtries.size < 2) return true"}
```

But i get exceptions : no such property GEOMTRIES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the field as type `nested` in the mapping, the typical `doc[fieldkey].values.size()` approached does not seem to work.  I found the following script to work:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : <SIZE>,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : "_source.containsKey('Geomtries') && _source['Geomtries'].size() == 1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NB: You must use `_source` instead of `doc`.

Comment: It worked!! just was need to remove the [].change to ***_source.Geomtries.size() == 1***

Comment: Great!! But, that's odd.  Wonder if someone has insights on that.  In an older version of Elasticsearch I have, that ['Geometries'] notation worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way you access fields in your script,  use:

```
doc['Geometry'].size()
or
_source.Geometry.size()
```

By the way for performance reasons,  I would denormalize and add GeometryNumber field. You can use the [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-transform.html) mapping to compute size at index time.

Comment: i'll check your suggestion thanks. but it didn't work

Comment: The 'values' was useless