# how to filter documents by nested docs count

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have following elasticsearch schema, where `leaves` is a `nested` field:

```
{
studentId:123,
studentName:'abc',
leaves:[
 {
  type:'casual',
  date:'2012-12-12'
 },
 {
  type:'sick',
  date:'2012-10-08'
 }
]
}
```

I want to filter/query the students having at least 2 holidays where holiday type is 'casual'.Just filter the documents, no aggregation required.
Have seen the question below which is old and uses deprecated 'filtered' query.
[elastic search filter by documents count in nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635074/elastic-search-filter-by-documents-count-in-nested-document)

My Elasticsearch version is 7.5

Comment: I would suggest to additionally index a new field that contains the number of elements in the nested array. It will be easier to build your query

Comment: thanks @Val is there any other way of achieving this in query, maybe through script or anything else?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the reference [DOC](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html)

```
GET /index/_search
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "inline": "doc['leaves'].values.length > 1 "

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Hariharan AR, but I get _No field found for [leaves] in mapping with types []_, maybe bcs its nested, also pls mention about the 'causal' type part of query.